# Using setval without SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, dbeaver

I am updating multiple sequences:

```
SELECT setval('sch.table_a', 123);
SELECT setval('sch.table_b', 50);
SELECT setval('sch.table_c', 5335410);
SELECT setval('sch.table_d', 1000);
SELECT setval('sch.table_e', 451213);
```

I use `dbeaver` tool to execute this script. The problem is, that due to the `SELECT` usage, it will open five distinct and unnecessary result windows.

I am trying to omit the `SELECT`, by using:`setval('sch.table_a', 123);` however its syntax seems to be invalid.

Can I use `setval` without `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `alter`?

```
alter sequence sch.table_a restart with 123;
alter sequence sch.table_b restart with 50;
alter sequence sch.table_c restart with 5335410;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT setval('sch.table_a', 123),
       setval('sch.table_b', 50),
       setval('sch.table_c', 5335410),
       ...;
```